# Radomly some keys are not working in KDE Neon

Tags: keyboard, kde-neon

I've installed KDE Neon recently. Randomly these keys are not working:

```
b,n,?,",ESC,Right Arrow,END
```

and after a few minutes they begin to work for a short time and later non-responsive again.

Previously I was using Linux Mint, and I didn't faced this problem before, so it is not an hardware issue. Also during boot I checked editing kernel parameters and these keys works. I think KDE Keyboard event subsystem is omitting these keys.

I tried different keyboard layouts, but same problem for same physical keys exists. I need help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

KDE Version: 5.95

Laptop: HP ZBook 15u G2 Mobile Workstation (latest BIOS installed)